# Difference between Widget and Stateless widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

In the Flutter docs they say that a Widget is a mutable configuration (description) for an Element, which I have no problem understanding.
But then we have the stateless widget, which extends the Widget class, and must implement a build method. The two classes look like they do the same job, can any one explain the difference ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Widget` is just an interface. You're never gonna use it directly, and this class does absolutely nothing.

It exists just for the compiler to know that your program is type-safe.

Comment: Thank you, I have just noticed that Widget is an abstract class, an that all widgets, like Container and Row, extend Stateless widgets and implement the build method.

Answer (score 0):

every thing with flutter made with widgets there is **no widget only** it is `Stateless` widgets and `statefull` widgets
and the `stateless` is static and the other is dynamic
stateless for fixed layouts 
 if you need any dynamic programming like(validation, requests, listeners for buttons and others..)
you need to use `Statefull` widgets
for more information see here..
[difference between stateless and statefull widgets](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/widgets-stateless-and-stateful-2e3b8adced71)

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)